# Code First from Existing Database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I've searched through SO on `Code First from Existing Database`, watched [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Code-First-to-Existing-Database-EF6-1-Onwards-), and read [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database).  I certainly understand how to generate the POCOs and Context using this method, but I'm not understanding the 'why'.

I prefer to build the database in SSMS, and have been happy using the `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` to generate the .edmx that houses my context.  The `Code First from Database` classes look pretty much the same, with some validation attributes added, and you get access to the modelBuilder.

I have no intention of altering the database structure via code.  Are the only benefits you get with this approach the ability to add custom validation, and manipulate how your models are built?  Is there an ideal scenario when you'd want to use `Code First from Database`?

Comment: It's been come to be known as "Database First Code Second". It's the way that I've been doing it and find it easy to work with. Unfortunately, I can't give specifics for why it's better. I do like how you make your own data classes (especially in a different Project), and can add instance methods to them instead of them being buried in the one file from Database First. (Though that could have changed and I don't know it.)

Comment: I've used Code First from Existing Database and add my own methods via `partial class`.

Comment: @krillgar half the struggle for me was realizing `Code First` doesn't necessarily mean code first.

Comment: @Jonesy what isn't *code first* in code first?

Comment: When I generate code from my pre-existing database my instinct is to call that database first

Comment: you know Code First from scratch, and have to use EF on an existing database. You feel more comfortable with code rather than with graphic interface; you are convinced than you can do more with a keyboard rather than with a mouse...

Comment: Code first can literally be code first, that is how I use it, it's pretty easy with DbMigrations and [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.113).aspx).  Deploy an application and watch the DB be created from scratch that didn't even exist... code first.

Comment: Right.  I know that, and understand that.  That wasn't really my question though.

Comment: Your title doesn't really match your question.  Do you want to know *HOW* to Code First with an existing database or do you want to know all the opinions of the last two sentences in your question (which then should be closed because they are primary opinion based)?

Comment: I want to know the benefits of `Code First from Existing Database` vs `Database First` model generation

Comment: Unfortunately, if you reword it to that, you'll most likely get closed as "Too Opinion Based".

Comment: If you ever have any questions on Entity Framework, the first place you should always go is wherever Julie Lehrman is at. She's fantastic. Check [her blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/) first to see if she has any posts that might help you out.

Comment: I've been watching her stuff on PluralSight today.  She is great.  Need her to cover EF6